# Annonate Data and group it by one Attribute

Tags: django

I have a Templatet that displays all Vulnerabilities grouped by Clients.
I use this Query  `qs = client.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('clientvul_set', clientvul.objects.select_related('VID')))` to selcet all related Vulnerabilties to one Client.
The clientvul Database also contains a `product` field. I also want to display how many vulnerabilities are in each `product`. If I try to prefetch_related first and then annonate the Data I get "attributeerror 'queryset' object has no attribute 'split'".
I can count the Data but cannout group it by a Client.

**Models.py**

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

class client(models.Model):
    client= models.CharField(max_length=50,primary_key=True)
    user= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    vuls = models.ManyToManyField(
        'vul',
        through='clientvul',
        related_name='client'
    )
    
 
class vul(models.Model):
    vid=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    cvelist=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    serverity=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    summary=models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class clientvul(models.Model):
    
    client= models.ForeignKey(client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vid=models.ForeignKey(vul, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    path=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    product=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    isActive=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
               fields=['client', 'vid'], name='unique_migration_host_combination' # legt client und VID als Primarykey fest
            )
        ]



admin.site.register(client)
admin.site.register(vul)
admin.site.register(clientvul)
```

view.py

```
def index(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(login_user)
    else:
        qs = client.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('clientvul_set', clientvul.objects.select_related('vid')))
        gProduct=(clientvul.objects
                        .values('Product')
                        .annotate(pcount=Count('Product'))
                        .order_by('-pcount')
                        )
                        
        querys={
            'data':qs,
            'groupedProduct':gProduct
        }
        print(querys)
        return render(request, 'browseDB.html',querys)
```

**template.html**

```
{% for row in data %}
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <table class="table">
        <thead class="table-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col"><h4>hostname</h4></th>
            <th scope="col"><h4>user</h4></th>
            <th class="text-right">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{ row.client }}-vul" data-parent="#myGroup">
                  Vulnerabilities
                </button>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th>
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{ row.client }}-software" data-parent="#myGroup">
                  Betroffene Software
                </button>
              </div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="hostname">{{ row.client }}</td>
            <td class="User">{{ row.user }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      
      <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="collapse indent" id="{{ row.client }}-vul">
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="{{ row.client }}-vul">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Severity</th>
                <th scope="col">CVE</th>
                <th scope="col">Path</th>
                <th scope="col">Status</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {% for subitem in row.clientvul_set.all %}
              <tr>
                <td class="Title">{{ subitem.VID.title }}</td>
                {% if "Critical" == subitem.VID.serverity %}
                <td class="Severity"><span class="badge bg-danger text-white">Critical</span></td>
                {% elif subitem.VID.Serverity == "High" %}
                <td class="Severity"><span class="badge bg-warning text-white">High</span></td>
                {% elif subitem.VID.Serverity == "Medium" %}
                <td class="Severity"><span class="badge bg-yellow text-dark">Medium</span></td>
                {% elif subitem.VID.Serverity == "Low" %}
                <td class="Severity"><span class="badge bg-success text-white">Low</span></td>
                {% endif %}
                <td class="CVE">
                  <a>{{ subitem.VID.cvelist}}</a>
                </td>
                <td class="Path">{{ subitem.path }}</td>
                {% if subitem.isactive == True %}
                <td class="isActive table-danger">aktiv</td>
                {% else %}
                <td class="isActive table-success">inaktiv</td>
                {% endif %}
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
<div class="collapse indent" id="{{ row.client }}-software">
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="{{ row.client }}-software">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Software</th>
                <th scope="col">Vulnerabilities</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {% for gproduct in groupedProduct %}
              <tr>
                <td class="Software">{{ gproduct.product }}</td>
                <td class="Vulnerabilities">{{ gproduct.pcount }}</td>
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}
```

I think im missing the part where I group the Data and match it to the other Queryset to display it correctly.